# props value is undefined in React js Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am writing a notepad web application. I am using React Hooks to use state variables. I am fetching data from an api using `axios`. Data contains a list of objects containing `_id`, `title`, `status` and `detail`. I am passing three values to `update button` as attributes and in `onClick()` method I am setting the values of my state variables using these attributes. Then these values are sent as props to a `UpdateTask` component. The probles is, two (_id and title) of those three variables are getting the correct value but one variable (detail) is getting undefined value. following is my code.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import UpdateTask from './UpdateTask.jsx';
import DeleteTask from './DeleteTask.jsx';



function Tasks()
{
    useEffect(()=>
    {
        async function fetchingData()
        {
            const tasks = await axios('http://127.0.0.1:8000/tasks');
            setTasks(tasks.data)
            
        };
        fetchingData();
    })

    function handleUpdateClick(e)
    {
        setViewUpdate(!viewUpdate);
        setUpdateId(e.target.id);
        setUpdateTitle(e.target.title);
        setUpdateDetail(e.target.detail);
        console.log(e.target)
    }

    function handleDeleteClick(e)
    {
        setViewDelete(!viewDelete);
        setDeleteId(e.target.id)
    }

    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

    const [viewUpdate, setViewUpdate] = useState(false);
    const [updateId, setUpdateId] = useState(null);
    const [updateTitle, setUpdateTitle] = useState('');
    const [updateDetail, setUpdateDetail] = useState('');

    const [viewDelete, setViewDelete] = useState(false);
    const [deleteId, setDeleteId] = useState(null);

    var listTasks = tasks.map((task)=>
    {
    return(
        <li className="main-task-list-items task-main" key={task._id} id={task._id}> 
            <h1>{task.title}</h1>
            <p>{task.detail}</p>
            <p>Status {task.status.toString()}</p>
            <button
                className="task-main-btn btn btn-primary"
                id={task._id}
                detail={task.detail}
                title={task.title}
                onClick={handleUpdateClick}
            >
                Update Task
            </button>
            <button
                className="task-main-btn btn btn-danger"
                id={task._id}
                onClick={handleDeleteClick}
            >
                Delete Task
            </button>
        </li>
        );
    })
    
    return(
        <div>
            <ul>{listTasks}</ul>
            {viewUpdate ? <UpdateTask title={updateTitle} detail={updateDetail} id={updateId} handleCancel={handleUpdateClick} /> : null }
            {viewDelete ? <DeleteTask id={deleteId} handleNo={handleDeleteClick}/> : null }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Tasks;
```

can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Try to log the tasks.Data and check if details exist in response

Comment: I have tried this. when I log `e.target` in `handleUpdateClick()` methos, it gives the element which contains all the attributes but when I log `e.target.detail` It gives undefined. P.S: when I log `e.target.title` It gives the correct value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding **onClick** by wrapping up with function and pass task -
`onClick={ () => handleUpdateClick(task)}`

```
function handleUpdateClick(task) {
        setViewUpdate(!viewUpdate);
        setUpdateId(task._id);
        setUpdateTitle(task.title);
        setUpdateDetail(task.detail);
}
```

Update this in your function call.!
Try this

You are able to get **id** and **title** because it comes under **eventtarget**. **Detail** is not the property of **eventTarget**. that might be the issue.